# LINQ - Join only one attribute with whole schema onf another entity

Tags: linq, select

I have two entities `smtracks` and `tracks_registration` I write the following linq

```
var track = from tracksData in sqlEntities.smtracks
join track_registrationData in sqlEntities.tracks_registration on tracksData.TracksID equals track_registrationData.FkTrackId
where tracksData.TracksID == 35 && track_registrationData.TuneCode == 5982234E
select new
{
    Tunecode = track_registrationData.TuneCode
};
```

now i just need this one attribute `Tunecode` from the other table and rest i want to have the whole schema of `smtracks` selected. The only way i know is that I select all the attributes in the LINQ above like

```
select new
    {
        Tunecode = track_registrationData.TuneCode
        TracksID = smtracks.TracksID
        SongTitle = smtracks.SongTitle
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
    };
```

and there are a lot of attributes, isn't there a simpler way to select the entire schema of one table and the just one attribute from other.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such mechanism to do what you want. The compiler does not derive properties from other objects, they must be explicitly included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind have extra parameter to hold the smtracks, then you can write like this :-

```
select new
{
   smtracks=tracksData ,
   Tunecode = track_registrationData.TuneCode
};
```

Later on you can get the value like smtracks.TracksID and so on.